# ElasticSearch – How Does It Perform When Queried With 1,000 Conditions

Tags: database, node.js, elasticsearch

I need to be able to search records that have any user ID within a group of user IDs in the query.

However, the amount of user IDs that must be searched will grow substantially over time.  Therefore, I must be able to add thousands of user IDs to a single query and search across all of them.

I'm considering using ElasticSearch for this via a managed service like bonsai.

How well does ElasticSearch perform when queried with thousands of conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on lots of things (number of servers, RAM, CPU, etc), and it will probably take some experimentation to figure out what works best for you. I'm confident that Elasticsearch can solve your problem, but it's hard to predict performance in general.

You might want to investigate [terms lookup](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_terms_lookup_mechanism). Basically you store all the terms for which you want to search in a document in the index (or another one), then you can reference that list in your search.

So you could save the IDs you want to search for as

```
PUT /test_index/idlist/1
{
    "ids" : [2,1982,939,1982,98716,7611,983838,...]
}
```

Then you can search another type using that list with something like this, for example, with a top-level filter:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "terms": {
         "id": {
            "index": "test_index",
            "type": "idlist",
            "id": "1",
            "path": "ids"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This probably only makes sense if you're going to run the same query more than once. You could have more than one list of IDs, though, and give the documents holding lists descriptive IDs if it helps.

Using a managed service makes it easy to experiment with different cluster setups (number of nodes, size of machines, data center, and so on). I would suggest you take a look at [Qbox](https://qbox.io/) (I'm biased, since I work with Qbox). New customers get a $40 introductory credit, which is usually enough to experiment with a proof of concept.

Comment: Sloan, this was a very helpful answer with a ton of useful information.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you could split your ids to batches (if you have millions of ids), and send the query multiple times, once for every batch. This will work faster than you think and might be suitable for your needs.